# Facebook Send Dialog in iframe doesn't seem to work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am having issues using the Facebook send dialog.  If I open this window in a new browser, everything works:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send
?app_id=[My_App_Id]
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcallback
&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimage.jpg
```

So by doing that, I am able to send a message just fine.  However, I need this to be in an iframe, which according to the send dialog documentation, this should work.  So I then do this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send
?app_id=[My_App_Id]
&display=iframe
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcallback
&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimage.jpg
```

Doing so, I get the following error:

```
API Error Code: 102
API Error Description: Session key invalid or no longer valid
Error Message: Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key
```

I find it a little strange that I can do this with a popup, but they require a session key for iframe.  But even so, that isn't a problem.  Because I have already gotten an access_token.  So, this should work then:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send
?app_id=[My_App_Id]
&display=iframe
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcallback
&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimage.jpg
&access_token=[MY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

The access token was obtained from calling /v12.0/dialog/oauth, and I have confirmed that the access_token is valid:

[image]

However, I now get this message:

```
This Content Isn't Available Right Now
When this happens, it's usually because the owner only shared it with a small group of people, changed who can see it or it's been deleted.
```

So now this really makes no sense.  I can send this link just fine if I use a popup with NO access_token present.  But to set the display to iframe, I must include the token, which is fine, but it doesn't like the token for some reason?

It is also worth noting that this behaves the same way regardless if the Facebook app is in development mode or live mode.  In development mode, all of the permissions should work for my test users.  So it seems very unlikely that this is a permissions issue?

Anybody have any insight on this at all?

Comment: The documentation says, _"If you are using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript, this will default to a modal `iframe` type"_ - which _could_ imply, that it can only be used in that context? (And in that case, it will not be an iframe created by you and placed somewhere in the page, it will still open a sort of modal dialog.)

Comment: If I don't add display=iframe, I get an error message that says: Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. So the only way to display it in an iframe is to set the display=iframe. But then the tokens don't work like I mentioned above...